# Preventing % to %20 in replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, servlets

I'm trying to format a string in a Java Servlet to add to a JDBC SELECT query. I need to replace `%20`'s with a `%` for my LIKE conditional.

```
nameQuery.replaceAll("%20", "%");
String query = String.format("SELECT name, imageURL FROM User " + 
"WHERE name LIKE \'%%%s%%\' AND userID != %d", nameQuery, userId);
```

With this code, all the `%20` still don't get replaced. For a `nameQuery` value like `"Allison%20s"`, calling `nameQuery.replaceAll("%20", "%")` changes it to `"Allison%20s"` (no change). Even escaping the `%` doesn't fix this. How can I make `replaceAll` convert the `%` to a `%20`?

Comment: `replaceAll` doesn't convert `%` to `%20`.

Comment: Looks like your queryString is urlEncoded

Comment: @ScaryWombat You're right. I edited my code to attempt to fix that, but `nameQuery.replaceAll("%20", "%")` is still not replacing `%20` to `%`.

Comment: why are you using `replaceAll` not `replace` ?

Comment: Off-Topic, but I would suggest using a PreparedStatement to prevent SQL Injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you've actually got is a string containing `%20` and you want to replace it with something else. You can do that with `replace`

```
nameQuery = nameQuery.replace("%20", "%"); // replace %20 with a %
```

You could also have used `replaceAll`, but you don't appear to be capturing the return value of `replaceAll`; just calling it and ignoring the result.